# tkiner how to get text from entry and make it global

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a rock paper scissor using tkinter and i have an entry where the user writes rock or paper or scissor

```
players_choice_entry = tkinter.Entry()
def check():
    
    players_choice = players_choice_entry.get()

check = tkinter.Button( text="Play", command=check)
```

how can i make players_choice global and use it outside the function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a variable set before the function is being run, such as `players-choice`. In the function, you declare the variable as global, and then runthe line of code you've written. All together it looks like this:

```
players_choice = ''
players_choice_entry = tkinter.Entry()
def check():
    global players_choice
    players_choice = players_choice_entry.get()

check = tkinter.Button( text="Play", command=check)
```

Comment: Yes you are right on that one but i still cant use it for example i cant print it out or use it in an if statement

Comment: You can. Inside and outside of the function, you can freely write print(players_choice) or use it as any other variable. If you have any other problem, comment and I'll help. Try and send all of your code if it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is there any text inside the entry? If not, then it won't print anything. Also, try starting the entry as tkinter.Entry(window).

Comment: i type in rock paper scissor

Comment: And do you look in the console? Try declaring a before the start of the mainloop

Comment: Also, try setting the text that you set it to to something like "check" at the start to see if it's not just printing the empty string